Proportional adjustment of CSS grid gap when resizing
I would like to create a collage with predefined fields and a fixed aspect ratio. The border and the grid gap should adapt dynamically to the size of the collage (should not always correspond to the viewport width). Percentage gap values are known to cause problems:

row-gap uses the height of the grid and then differs from column-gap
a large gap leads to an overflow of the grid



:root {
  --border: 5%;
  --gap: 5%;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  gap: var(--gap);
  padding: var(--border);
  background: red;
  width: 100%;
  aspect-ratio: 2;
}

.grid div {
  background: blue;
  &:nth-child(1) {
    grid-column: 1/6;
    grid-row: 1/4;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 6/10;
    grid-row: 1/4;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: 10/13;
    grid-row: 1/6;
  }
  &:nth-child(4) {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: 4/8;
  }
  &:nth-child(5) {
    grid-column: 4/10;
    grid-row: 4/10;
  }
  &:nth-child(6) {
    grid-column: 10/13;
    grid-row: 6/10;
  }
  &:nth-child(7) {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: 8/13;
  }
  &:nth-child(8) {
    grid-column: 4/9;
    grid-row: 10/13;
  }
  &:nth-child(9) {
    grid-column: 9/13;
    grid-row: 10/13;
  }
}
<div id="collage" class="grid">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
  <div>7</div>
  <div>8</div>
  <div>9</div>
</div>



CodePen

Not completely sure what you're trying to achieve here. Maybe using empty columns/rows instead of gaps might work. Or maybe you can put the whole thing in a container query and use container query units for gap sizing? You mention a border but I don't see one. And if not always corresponding to viewport width what should gaps correspond to? The collage sizes? But they're fixed in size to the viewport width.

@ZachJensz Thanks for your questions and the edit. The border is the padding around the grid. The gaps should be the same dimension and adjust relatively to the collage size (regardless of width or height, because the aspect ratio should remain the same). The width of the collage naturally only corresponds to the viewport width in this example and should later take up 100% of a parent element.

For  the effect you require you need container units i.e. cqw: 1% of a query container's width.
Unfortunately, these units only apply to children of the respective container not the container itself.
Thus, if you wrap the grid in a new container, you can specify gap and padding in container units.


:root {
  --gap: 5cqw;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  background: lightblue;
  container-type: inline-size;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  gap: var(--gap);
  padding: var(--gap);
  background: red;
  aspect-ratio: 2;
}

.grid div {
  background: blue;
  display:grid;
  place-items:center;
  color:white;
  &:nth-child(1) {
    grid-column: 1/6;
    grid-row: 1/4;
  }
  &:nth-child(2) {
    grid-column: 6/10;
    grid-row: 1/4;
  }
  &:nth-child(3) {
    grid-column: 10/13;
    grid-row: 1/6;
  }
  &:nth-child(4) {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: 4/8;
  }
  &:nth-child(5) {
    grid-column: 4/10;
    grid-row: 4/10;
  }
  &:nth-child(6) {
    grid-column: 10/13;
    grid-row: 6/10;
  }
  &:nth-child(7) {
    grid-column: 1/4;
    grid-row: 8/13;
  }
  &:nth-child(8) {
    grid-column: 4/9;
    grid-row: 10/13;
  }
  &:nth-child(9) {
    grid-column: 9/13;
    grid-row: 10/13;
  }
}
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="collage" class="grid">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
    <div>3</div>
    <div>4</div>
    <div>5</div>
    <div>6</div>
    <div>7</div>
    <div>8</div>
    <div>9</div>
  </div>
</div>




Thank you so much for your reply @Paulie_D. This works really well until the border/padding and/or the gap get too big (it should be possible for the user to change this dynamically at a later stage). Then grid kind of "explodes" and the aspect ratio gets destroyed. Or can a maximum gap be determined?

There's no such thing as max-gap unfortunately. You'd have to use actual container queries or media queries to adjust the gap at whatever width is required.

If the gap is to be user determined you could set the variable to be --gap: 5 and then the gap/padding as gap: calc(1cqw * var(--gap)); - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/OJemvvO

Hmmm... you might be able to limit the gap.. lemme think. Yes, you can using min() - see the updated codepen.
